# Error al Realizar Consulta

Tags: php, mvc, pdo

Buen@s días, Tardes o noches.
Estoy intentando hacer un pequeño `crud` en `PHP` con un sistemas de `login`, pero al momento de mandar a  validar los datos de acceso me sale el mensaje de error `Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function prepare() on null`.

les dejo una imágenes con el código para ver si me pueden apoyar a resolver el Error

1.- LoginModel

```
<?php
require_once "Config/database.php";

class LoginModel {
   
    public function Validar() {    
        try {
            $prepare=null;
            $ResultSet=null;
            // Recuperamos la conexión
            $con =database::getConnect();
            // Consulta
            $sth = $con->prepare("SELECT P.Nombre,P.Apellido_Paterno,P.Apellido_Materno, U.Nom_Usuario,U.Contraseña
            FROM persona AS P, usuarios AS U, empleado AS E
            WHERE   U.IdClave = E.idClave AND E.IdPersona = P.IdPersona AND U.Nom_Usuario = ? AND U.Contraseña = ?");
            //$prepate = $con->prepare($sql);
            $sth->bindParam(1, $usuario);
            $sth->bindParam(2, $pdw);
            //$pdoExec = $ResultSet->execute(array(":USU"=>$usuario, ":PASS"=>$pdw));
            $sth->execute();
            $cantidad_resultado = $sth->rowCount();    
            if ($cantidad_resultado == 0) {    
               header("location:ErroresController/Method");    
            }                     
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            echo 'ERROR!';
            print_r( $e );    
        } 
    }
}

esta la clase del loginController    
2.- Conexion Con PDO
    
    
    <?php
    
    class database {
    
        public static function getConnect(){
            $servidor = "localhost";
            $usuario = "root";
            $password = "";
            try{
                $cnt = new PDO("mysql:host=$servidor;dbname=cases", $usuario, $password);      
                $cnt->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
                return $cnt;
            }catch (PDOException $e) {
                echo "La conexión ha fallado: " . $e->getMessage();
            }
        }
    }
    
    
    3.- LoginController
    
    <?php
    
class LoginController {
    
    public function Index(){
        require_once "View/Start/Login.php";
    }

    public function Entrar(){
            $usuario = $_POST["Usuario"];
            $pdw = $_POST["pdw"];
        if (isset($usuario) && isset($pdw)) {        
            require_once "Models/LoginModel.php";
            $validar = new LoginModel();
            $validar->validar($usuario, $pdw);        
        } else {
            /*header("location:../index.php");*/
            echo "No se Pudo";
        }
    }
}

4.- Error en el navegador

[![Error de navegador al ejecutar el codigo][4]][4]


Espero que me puedan ayudar, de antemano muchas gracias.
```

Comment: Hola. Pon los trozos de código como texto, no como imagen. Pulsa en [edit] para ello. Sí el resultado de `prepare` es nulo podría deberse a que la consulta es errónea o a que la conexión es nula. Dicho eso, deberías evitar el uso de `ñ`, acentos y caracteres especiales en las nominaciones, rompen el código si no manejas adecuadamente la codificación de caracteres en los diferentes contextos.

Comment: Tú conexión es nula. Sugiero lo siguiente: 1. En el `catch` donde creas la conexión pon al final un: **`return null;`** 2. En la parte del `prepare` verifica primero que la conexión no sea nula con algo como: **`if ($con) { //aquí el prepare y todo lo relativo a él } else { echo "No hay conexión. Verifica tus credenciales"; }`**